# How to add SQL Server record from Visual Studio 2013 (windows form)?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

To be honest, I really don't know anything about Visual Studio 2013...

Here are the list of what have I done...

1. Created a table in SQL Server
2. Create a Windows Form in VS
3. Add connection to database

Then now I want to insert 2 records at the same time by 1 button...

I have 4 textboxes such as :

- Name1
- Name2
- Value1
- Value2

Then after I click the "Save" Button, these 2 records should be in the SQL table :

```
|  Name 1  |  Value 1  |
|  Name 2  |  Value 2  |
```

And there is nothing in my VS code, only :

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days I try everything, at last I found my answer.
I should update the Visual Studio Express 2013 first to be connected to SQL Server.
Then open the Data Source and drag the table name to the windows form.
Finally the table is callable.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a table. write data in it. And the you can show it on `datagridview`.

Go through this links:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f50501/search-records-in-windows-form-from-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to establish your connection with sql server
dim connection as:

```
sqlconnection = new sqlconnection ("Data Source= Name of server; Inetial catalog=name of Database; Integrated security = True;)
```

click on add button 
open the connection using:

```
connection.open();
dim adddata as sqlcommand= new sqlcommand ("insert into emp (Name,name2,Value1, Value2) values ('"& textbox1.text&"', '"& textbox2.text&"', '"& textbox3.text&"','"& textbox4.text&"')connection);
adddate.executenonquiry();
connection.close();
```

Msgbox."Data added to Sql"